# How to read config values either using .ENV file or user secrets in Azure Functions

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I created an Azure function with .Net Core 3.1, that is triggered when a new messages to the Service Bus Queue is added. This function works well by hardcoding the connection string directly to the local.settings.json file.

Now, I want to go one step further I avoid hardcoding this value by putting it either in an .ENV file or user secrets. I tried those two but is not working so far.

The local.host.json

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "MyServiceBusConnString": "${MY_CONNECTIONSTRING}"
  }
}
```

This is the Startup.cs I created

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using DemoFunction;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

// register the assembly
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace DemoFunction
{
    // inherit
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        private IConfiguration configuration;

        // override
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            // In other examples the registration of services goes here
        }

        public override void ConfigureAppConfiguration(IFunctionsConfigurationBuilder builder)
        {
            // local dev no Key Vault
                builder.ConfigurationBuilder
                   .SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
                   .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", true)
                   .AddUserSecrets(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), true)
                   .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                   .Build();
        }
    }
}
```

This Startup code is the last one I tried but I have seem different approaches how to do it. Already tried them without any luck. Here are the links:

[AZURE FUNCTIONS CONFIGURATION AND SECRETS MANAGEMENT](https://damienbod.com/2020/07/12/azure-functions-configuration-and-secrets-management/)

[Using JSON and User Secrets configuration with Azure Functions](https://dev.to/cesarcodes/using-json-and-user-secrets-configuration-with-azure-functions-3f7g)

And this part of my function:

```
public class MyFunction
{
    private ILogger _logger;

    [FunctionName("MyFunction")]
    public string Run([ServiceBusTrigger("myQueue", Connection = "MyServiceBusConnString")] string queueItem, ILogger log)
    {
        _logger = log;

        _logger.LogInformation($"Starting Azure Function...");

        // custom code...
    }
}
```

Look at the Connection property of ServiceBusTrigger. It's referencing the key from the local.host.json which in turn is trying to read the value as mentioned before from .ENV file or user secrets.

When I run the Azure Function, this is the error I am getting:

[image: Screenshot Error]

At this point, I'm kind of lost on how to achieve this. So, any comment on how to fix this or any guidance is very appreciated.

Comment: not sure about this error, but can you look into this [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=windows) for managing these secrets in a better way using dotnet cli

Answer (score 0):

For local development you can leave as it is, however, when publishing to Azure you should use Azure Key Vault to proper store the secrets of your application.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references#reference-syntax